# error: expected ')' before 'PRId64'

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

Использую Code::Blocks (16.01) для переноса проекта с Win7 (VS2013) на Ubuntu (Code::Blocks). С переносом возникли проблемы. Решил попробовать с Code::Blocks на Windows. Возникла следующая проблема: при сборке появляется ошибка:

> error: expected ')' before 'PRId64'

На строке:

```
snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=0x%" PRIx64,
            data.iccx[i]->sample_rate, av_get_sample_fmt_name(data.iccx[i]->sample_fmt), data.iccx[i]->channel_layout);
```

Пробел стоит перед `PRIx64`. Включена поддержка `С++11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И что такое ваше `PRIx64`? Скорее всего какой-то макрос, который разворачивался в строковый литерал типа `u` или там `ul` - судя про предыдущей строке. Вероятно, этот макрос более не определен, и ваш компилятор полагает его идентификатором...

**PS** Ну конечно, как я и предполагал - этот макрос прописано в `inttypes.h`, скорее всего у вас не прописан путь к Windows Kits или что-то в этом роде.

И еще раз - Code::Blocks *не является компилятором*, это *среда программирования*.

**PPS (добавление @Dmitry)**

Поскольку проект планируется переносить на Ubuntu, то использовать заголовочные файлы для Windows - нежелательно. Решение скопировать определение макроса:

```
#define PRIx64 __PRI_64_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ "x"
#define __PRI_64_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ "ll"
```

Comment: Добавил `#include "inttypes.h" #include "Windows.h"` ничего не изменилось. Да, поэтому установил и в ubuntu и в Win7 g++4.9

Comment: @Dmitry с чего Вы решили, что макрос `PRIx64` сугубо виндовый? Так же вызывают вопросы: порядок дефайнов (в первом используется второй); возможное переопределение дефайнов (без явного `#undef`); определение имен, начинающихся с двойного подчеркивания (такие имена зарезервированы для компилятора).

Answer (score 3):

Возможная причина отсутствия макроса `PRId64` в том, что перед `#include <cinttypes>` надо добавить `#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS`.